# how do I calculate inverse modulo of a number when the modulus is not prime?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I came through Fermat's Little theorem, and it provides a way to calculate inverse modulo of a number when modulus is a prime. but how do I calculate something like this

37inverse mod 900?

Comment: Extended Euclidean algorithm. That's usually also better when the modulus is prime.

Comment: okay.. thank you. I'll go through the algorithm :)

Comment: not all numbers have inverses under modulo m if m is not prime.  If your modulus is 6, for example, then 2 has no inverse, since no number times 2 yields 1 mod 6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Euclidean algorithm and basic algebra we get

$900=24*37+12 \rightarrow 900-24*37=12$

$37=3*12+1 \rightarrow 37-3(900-24*37)=1$

Therefore $73*37-3*900=1$. So the inverse of 37 mod 900 is 73.

Answer (score 4):

We describe a way that is analogous to the Fermat Theorem approach. For large moduli $M$ whose rime power factorization is **known** the method is reasonably efficient. However, the Extended Euclidean Algorithm offers a better path to the inverse.

We first calculate $\varphi(900)$. From the prime power factorization $2^2 3^25^2$ of $900$, this is $(2)(6)(20)=240$. Thus 
$$37^{240}\equiv 1\pmod{900},$$
and therefore the inverse of $37$ is congruent to $37^{239}$ modulo $900$.

**Remark:** Instead of using the Euler $\varphi$-function, we can use the Carmichael function $\lambda$. In our case, we have $\lambda(900)=\text{lcm}(2,6,20)=60$ and therefore the inverse of $37$ modulo $900$ is congruent to $37^{59}$ modulo $900$.

Comment: Wow ,just the answer I was looking for . Thanks

Comment: Though I have a vague idea about it but it will be really helpful if you could explain why did you write 37^(239) , from the equation 37^(240) ≡ 1 ? That change of 240 to 239.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: can you elaborate bit more ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to solve:

$$ax\equiv 1\mod b$$

If the two numbers $a$, $b$ are coprime ($\gcd(a,b)=1$), then there exist $u,v$ such that

$$
ua+vb=1
$$

(Obviously, if $b$ is prime, then $a,b$ are always coprime.)  You find the numbers $u,v$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm, just as you do when $b$ is prime.

This means that:

\begin{align}
ua\equiv1&\mod b \\
x\equiv uax\equiv u&\mod b
\end{align}

If $a,b$ are not coprime, then the Extended Euclidean algorithm will give you:

$$
ua+vb=d
$$

where $d=\gcd(a,b)$.  You can then write $a=jd$ and $b=kd$ to get:

\begin{align}
ujd+vkd&=d\\
uj+vk&=1
\end{align}

Use that to solve the following, equivalent, congruence instead, using the same method:

$$
jx\equiv 1\mod k
$$

Answer (score 0):

Though many methods using Euclidean algorithm are mentioned but if you want to calculate $x$ $mod$  $m$  $\forall 1 \leq i \leq m - 1 $, You can simply use the recursion

$$inv[i] = -\lfloor m/i \rfloor * inv[n \% i] $$

The proof is simple,  Consider,

$n = x*(\lfloor m/i \rfloor) + (n \% x)$

$n - (n \% x) = x * (\lfloor m/i \rfloor)$

and take modulo on both sides.